# How to run adb commands in VB.NET

Tags: android, vb.net, adb

I am studying android and .NET

I would like to use VB.NET to execute adb command

For example, I would like to enable or disable airplane mode from PC to Android phone

such as

> adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 1
>   adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
Dim psi2 As New ProcessStartInfo
psi.WorkingDirectory = "C:\ad\adsystem\adb file"
psi.Arguments = "adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 0"
psi.FileName = "adb"
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
Process.Start(psi)

psi2.WorkingDirectory = "C:\ad\adsystem\adb file"
psi2.Arguments = "adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state false"
psi2.FileName = "adb"
psi2.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
Process.Start(psi)
```

I tried to use example from

[How to get Output of a Command Prompt Window line by line in Visual Basic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347823/how-to-get-output-of-a-command-prompt-window-line-by-line-in-visual-basic)

[Shell commands in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795723/shell-commands-in-vb)

However, It didn't really work and i am not really sure why ....

is there anyway to run adb command from VB.NET?

thanks

Comment: for starters `.Arguments` should not include the `.FileName`. the command you are trying to run is `adb adb shell ...`

Comment: I have a question. Can we do like Shell("cmd.exe /c cd adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 0", AppWinStyle.Hide). Like this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cmd.exe` to communicate with `adb commands` see my code example.

Declaring new process and process info

```
Dim My_Process As New Process()
Dim My_Process_Info As New ProcessStartInfo()
```

Using `cmd.exe` as the filename of my process.

```
My_Process_Info.FileName = "cmd.exe"
```

in argument you can use adb commands like this.

```
My_Process_Info.Arguments = "/c adb devices"
```

`/c` Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates.

Now set WorkingDirectory for adb.exe in cmd.exe. Don't confuse, it is same as `cd` command. Setting our working Directory to where your adb.exe file exists.

```
My_Process_Info.WorkingDirectory = "Directory of your adb.exe file"
```

Now some necessary settings for process.

```
My_Process_Info.CreateNoWindow = True  ' Show or hide the process Window
My_Process_Info.UseShellExecute = False ' Don't use system shell to execute the process
My_Process_Info.RedirectStandardOutput = True  '  Redirect (1) Output
My_Process_Info.RedirectStandardError = True  ' Redirect non (1) Output
My_Process.EnableRaisingEvents = True ' Raise events
My_Process.StartInfo = My_Process_Info
```

Setting completed, Now start the process.

```
My_Process.Start()
```

If you want to get the reply/result of your sended adb command you can use [StandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) property of the process.

```
Dim Process_ErrorOutput As String = My_Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() ' Stores the Error Output (If any)
Dim Process_StandardOutput As String = My_Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() ' Stores the Standard Output (If any)
```

Example Function:

```
Function adb(ByVal Arguments As String) As String
    Try

        Dim My_Process As New Process()
        Dim My_Process_Info As New ProcessStartInfo()

        My_Process_Info.FileName = "cmd.exe" ' Process filename
        My_Process_Info.Arguments = Arguments ' Process arguments
        My_Process_Info.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Users\<Your User Name>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools" 'this directory can be different in your case.
        My_Process_Info.CreateNoWindow = True  ' Show or hide the process Window
        My_Process_Info.UseShellExecute = False ' Don't use system shell to execute the process
        My_Process_Info.RedirectStandardOutput = True  '  Redirect (1) Output
        My_Process_Info.RedirectStandardError = True  ' Redirect non (1) Output

        My_Process.EnableRaisingEvents = True ' Raise events
        My_Process.StartInfo = My_Process_Info
        My_Process.Start() ' Run the process NOW

        Dim Process_ErrorOutput As String = My_Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() ' Stores the Error Output (If any)
        Dim Process_StandardOutput As String = My_Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() ' Stores the Standard Output (If any)

        ' Return output by priority
        If Process_ErrorOutput IsNot Nothing Then Return Process_ErrorOutput ' Returns the ErrorOutput (if any)
        If Process_StandardOutput IsNot Nothing Then Return Process_StandardOutput ' Returns the StandardOutput (if any)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try

    Return "OK"

End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)     Handles Button1.Click

    'Usage:

    'Get the list of connected devices.
    MsgBox(adb("/c adb devices")) 

    'Connect your phone wirelessly using wifi (required phone I.P)
    MsgBox(adb("/c adb disconnect 192.168.xx.xx:5555")) 

    'Get the list of connected devices.
    MsgBox(adb("/c adb devices"))

    'Put your phone on airplane mode. 
    MsgBox(adb("/c adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 1"))

End Sub
```